# How to configure Laravel project structure in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: php, laravel, intellij-idea

Which folders I'm supposed to mark as Sources/Resources/Excluded?

[image]

Comment: This is just to organize yourself better ? 
Or you encounter a problem with Laravel into your IDE ?
(also here is a little article from JetBrains that explain what are the purpose of each directory types : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/directories.html)

Comment: To organize myself better. Your link helps a lot, I didn't find it when searched documentation. So basically I should mark `app` as `Sources` and `public` as `Resources`. Should I exclude vendor folder? How about storage?

Comment: Just a follow up question: Is IntelliJ IDEA not just for / focused on java? It does not include everything from PHPStorm right?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA includes features from all other Jetbrains IDEs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*My own logic* based on [the PHPStorm guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/directories.html)

### Sources

```
The root folder
```

**reasoning**: Your source code can be in mutliple folder inside the root.

**alternative**: Just mark the real folder you have your code inside `app, bootstrap, config, routes, (more...)`

> Click this button to mark the selected folder as the root for
> namespaces used in your project. Based on this setting, PhpStorm
> suggests you the proper folder name when you want to create a new
> namespace under another parent namespace during creation or moving a
> PHP class, that is, when you are actually creating or moving a PHP
> class to a non-existing namespace under another parent namespace. If
> no Sources folder is specified, you will have to type the proper
> folder manually.
>
> Appointing a Sources folder is not mandatory but this helps you keep
> your project structure in compliance with the PSR0 and PSR4 standards.
> See Configuring PHP Namespaces in a Project for details.

### Tests

```
tests
```

**reasoning**: For obvious reasons your tests live there by default. It might be possible you use some test library for your javascript code that lives in another folder.

> Click this button to mark the selected folder as a test root.

### Excluded

```
vendor, storage, node_modules
```

**reasoning**: All (composer) libraries we use in our project live in vendor, but are not our own code. We should not search trough it by default.
In storage live caching files, files that have no significant meaning to us, we do not track them in version control (like vendor). We could just delete them and the application would still work. Same for node_modules, but this directory is for javascript packages.

> Click this button to mark the selected folder as excluded so PhpStorm
> ignores it during indexing, parsing, and code completion.

### Resource Root

```
public
```

**reasoning**: Your own frontend assets should be (somewhere) under the public folder to serve to the browser. Frontend assets are (mostly?) files, javascript and css.

> Click this button to enable PhpStorm to complete relative paths to
> resources under the selected folder.

Comment: If anybody feels this information is incomplete or incorrect, please comment or edit so we can make this guide better!

Comment: Excluding the vendor folder won't generate a missing of autocompletion/intellisense of certain class? Taking example of a new laravel project won't be better if we select as "Project Root" the main folder and then select Resource Root, Excluded Folder and Test Folder after this step? (Look at this screen http://prntscr.com/pxsn3c)

Comment: Personnaly, I would simply add node_modules to "Excluded" as well.

Comment: @GuillaumePommier agreed